# Scheduled push notifications - inside Node.js function or CRON job?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, push-notification, backend

I have to implement scheduled push notifications in backend (Node.js) which are triggered only at certain time. So I need to query DB (PostgreSQL) in interval 1-2 minutes and find only those notifications which need to be triggered.

What is the better solution?

1. Use internal setTimeout query function
   or
2. External CRON script which will trigger querying function in Node.js?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second option is just a cron that makes an HTTP request to your service, its pretty equivalent.  If, instead the solution is packaged as a script and the cron drives that script directly it has a couple of tradeoffs, mainly based around operations:

> Use internal setTimeout query function or

This means you have to launch a long running service,  and to keep it running. Things like memory leaks *may* become an issue.

> External CRON script which will trigger querying function in Node.js?

This is the strategy that [google GCP uses for its cron offering](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml).  If the function just pings a web url the solutions are pretty equivalent.

---

IMO, The biggest issue with both of these is being careful about coupling a background (async) workload with an online workload.  If your service is servicing real time live HTTP requests, but is also running these background workloads that takes resources away from servicing synchronous HTTP requests.  If they are two fundamentally different workloads than it also makes sense to separate them for scaling purposes.

I've been in a situation where monitoring has actually informed this decision.  The company used prometheus and didn't have push gateway installed.  So a cron based solution had 0 metric visibility, but the service version was trivial to add metrics / alerting.